# What is tern feature in eclipse angular 2 plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want install eclipse angular 2 plugin from marketplace. In installation process I get to select plugin features an in list is "Tern features" & "Tern tooling" what it is?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At first AngularJS Eclipse 1.2.0 is for Angular1 and not for Angular2.

If you wish to develop Angular2, please install [Angular2 Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) which provides TypeScript and Angular2 support for Eclipse.

[Tern](http://ternjs.net/) is a JavaScript inference engine which is able to analyze your JavaScript, create AST and provide completion, hover, navigation, etc for any editor (Sublime, Atom, Eclipse, etc).

[Angular2 Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) uses **tsserver** provided by TypeScript, which plays the same goal than tern.